# What is the term for a situation where you need to do first in order to do second, but to do first you need to do second?

Tags: terminology

Practical example:

> In order to get a job you need experience. To have experience you need
>   to get a job.

What is the right term to call this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The English term you're looking for is [Catch-22](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_%28logic%29).

It comes from the title of the 1961 novel *Catch-22*, by Joseph Heller.

Comment: Good. Never expected it to contain numbers. It makes me doubt about the usage in a sentence. "Catch-22 is that I need experience in order to get a job, but..." - doesn't feel correct. Is it?

Comment: "The fact that I need experience to get a job, but need a job to get experience, is a cache-22"

Comment: @user85686 That's what internships are all about.

Comment: @Alph.Dev the sentence you presented may be grammatically correct, but it sounds off to this native American English speaker.  Instead I would have said "**The** catch-22 is that I need experience in order to get a job."

Comment: @Lumberjack Thank you for pointing that out. As English is neither my primary nor secondary language, I just don't know how it sounds.

Comment: A catch-22 is a paradox, but IIRC it wasn't a temporal paradox.  (Rather it required to approach discharge by both asking and not asking, which is mutually exclusive with no time element)

Answer (score 4):

Also *circular dependency* or *chicken-and-egg problem* or *(temporal) paradox*.